# Typescript folder structure confusing

Tags: angular, typescript

This is my folder structure:

```
projectRoot
projectRoot/app
projectRoot/app/main.ts
projectRoot/app/factoryClasses/Person.ts
projectRoot/node_modules/*angular 2 files*
```

inside my main.ts is an import statement

```
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';

import { AppModule } from './app.module';

import { Person } from './factoryClasses/Person.ts';//this works
import { Person } from 'factoryClasses/Person.ts';//this doesn't

platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule,TestModule);
```

My main.ts is inside the app/ folder but why is main.ts looking for the file in `projectRoot/node_modules/factoryClasses/Person.ts`
instead of
`projectRoot/app/factoryClasses/Person.ts`? This is from the angular.io quick start by the way.

Comment: `./` means current directory (of the current file), otherwise it defaults to root directory. On another note `../` means go up one level. It's just basic unix syntax.

Comment: Yes but WHY?, the relative path of main.ts should be the app/ folder, so why is it looking for a file in node_modules/ folder, is it possible to make an angular app without the node_modules/ folder?

Comment: I don't think you can escape `node_modules`. You'll need it for `@angular/..` and pretty much other libraries you add will be referenced from here.I think this reading might help https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/module-resolution.html .

Comment: Can you share your `systemjs.config.js` file? It could be an issue with your mappings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your tsconfig.json file, you'll see one of the properties is "moduleResolution".  If you have it set to "node" (which the quickstart does unless you've changed it), then is uses nodejs rules for resolving relative paths.

```
{
  ...
  "moduleResolution": "node",
  ...
}
```

You can read more about it [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/module-resolution.html).